# Portal - New Tab Issue

Tags: websphere-portal

I have a program capable of displaying two sets of portlet. One for the customer and one for employee. I have a link in the screen so that I could switch between the two. When the link is click, it will redirect into two different urls.

1. Employee - `my_url/employee?language=en`
2. Customer - `my_url/customer?language=en`

My problem is, when I am in the screen for customer, then I click the employee link it shows perfect. But when I open a new tab in the browser then type my_url, it always shows the customer screen. The desire behavior is it should display the employee screen since it is  the screen in my previous tab.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the page hierarchy? Is the Employee page the first page where user has access? If that is the case, it will be loaded when you access 'my_url'